# Move Exchange mailbox folders for a set of users from the command line / bulk

Tags: exchange

I would like to know of a way to move a number of folders for a set of users in bulk without their interaction. I'm assuming Powershell or Exchange Management Shell are the best options but I've not got much experience with either.

If users have sub folders of the Inbox I'd like to know how we can move these folders to the same level as the inbox. Or to a separate top level folder.

I'd like to be able to perform this on bulk for a large number of users. The user list could be a CSV input if needed.

Has anyone done this before? What is the best solution to this other than getting the user to do it themselves?